# Google Ads broad match keyword: Show keywords for clicks

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads

I have a broad match keyword-phrase (`+keyword1 +keyword2 +keyword2`), which was clicked multiple times in my Google Ads account.

How can I display the exact phrases where the clicks came from? As it is a broad match something like this is possible: `+keyword1 +keyword2 +keyword2 something else`

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, not put my nose into Google Ads in eons.
If you run a search terms report, it should show you the search term (query) that someone used that matched to your keyword. Keep in mind a search term may have a different match type to your keyword match type eg if you are using +hot +chocolate as a modified broad match keyword and I searched for hot chocolate it would show my search term as being an exact match for your modified broad match keyword.

More info on the Search Term report can be found in the Google Ads help center
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2472708?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

**How can I display the exact phrases where the clicks came from**
answer: you can check the source where the clicks came from by follow these steps

1. Go to the campaign level
2. Click on locations
3. Click on the GEOGRAPHICAL REPORT
   [image]
4. And pick the country you want to see the breakdown of the clicks

In the search term report you might find differently arrange keywords since you are using broad match modified.

Example 1:
+hot +chocolate
it will show chocolate hot

example 2:
+women's +hats
it will show hats for women